# Were my pipes frozen or was my pilot out?

Tags: water, gas, heater

If the pilot goes out on a gas water heater and i turn on "hot water" only at a sink will cold water come out or will no water come out?  I already fixed the hot water problem and got it running again but i was assured it was frozen pipes and i do not think this was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the heat source is off on the water heater, but no valves were closed, water will still come out of the hot tap. It may even still be warm-ish if you have a tank water heater, depending on how long the water has been in the tank with no heating. If no water is coming out, or water is coming out more slowly than normal, that could be an indication of a frozen pipe (it could be other things, too).

Comment: I've dealt with frozen pipes before.  Once i re-lit the pilot and got the tank running again water came rushing back to the faucet.  Also cold water was  still able to run just fine the entire time.  I wasn't sure if there was some safety feature on some tanks.